# How to create two different windows with different urls using selenium/C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Here is the test case:

- Open chrome with url1
- Do some operations
- Open another window with url2
- Do some operations on the new window
- Switch to first window and check for some results

I need to know how to create two different windows with same chrome driver instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void InteractWithTwoWindowsFromSameChromeDriverInstance()
    {
        var driver = new ChromeDriver( @"C:\temp");

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text']").SendKeys("a");

        driver.ExecuteScript("window.open('http://www.bing.com')");
        
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());  // switch to new window
        driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='search']").SendKeys("b");
        
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());  // go back to original window
    }
```

Comment: What is ExecuteScript from driver.ExecuteScript("window.open('http://www.bing.com')")

Comment: Executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. See more here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html